# Strange notation in the article about sparse self-attention

Tags: machine-learning, linear-algebra, natural-language-processing

While reading an article devoted to the sparse self-attention, I came across a notation that was not very clear:

$$
Attend(X, S) =
\Big(
a(x_i, S_i)
\Big)_{i∈{\{1,...,n}\}}
$$

What means $\Big( \space \space \Big)_{i∈{\{1,...,n}\}}$     ?

It would be great to describe this in more detail.

Link to the article (page 4): https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.10509.pdf

Please Help!

Thank You for your answers.

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about the topic in the paper, but could it be the case that they're referring to a [family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_family)?

If you take an initial segment of $\mathbb{N}$,  $I = \{1, 2, ..., n\}$ then a family $(x_i)_{i \in I} = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ can be thought of as the generalization of a tuple (but $I$ can in theory be arbitrary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation

$$(x_i)_{i \in \{1,\dots,n\}}$$

is short-hand for

$$(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n).$$

Just two different ways to write the same thing.

It is analogous to the relationship between $\sum_{i \in \{1,\dots,n\}} x_i$ and $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n$.  Two different ways to write the same thing.